# req.body returns undefinded after setting bodyParser urlencoded to extended as false

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

I am a newbee to nodejs . I have tried to create simple chat App. The **req.body** in my app.post seems to return undefinded  even after setting my body-parser **urlencoded ({extented:false})**.can anybody walk me through this?!..thanks in advance

here is my code server.js for server side:

```
var express = require('express')
 var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
 var app = express()

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(express.static(__dirname))

var messages = [
{name:'Brue',message:'Hello Diana'},
{name:'Diana', message:'Hey Bruce.'} ]

app.get('/messages', (req,res) => {
res.send(messages) })

app.post('/messages', (req,res) => {
messages.push(req.body)
res.sendStatus(200)})

var server = app.listen(8080, (err,data) => {
console.log('The server runs on the port:', server.address().port) })
```

here is my client side code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"> <head> <meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Message App</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<br>
<div class="jumbotron"> 

    <h1 class="display-4"> Send Message  </h1>
    <br>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Name">
    <br>
    <textarea placeholder = "Message" class="form-control" id="mesage" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    <br>
    <button id = "send" class="btn btn-success"> Send</button>
    </div>
<div id="messages"></div>
</div>

<script>
$(() => {
$('#send').click(() => {
    var message = { name: $("#name").val(), message: $("#message").val()}
    postMessage(message)

})
getMessages() })

function addMessages(message){
$("#messages").append(`<h4>${message.name}</h4> <p> ${message.message}  </p>`) }

function getMessages(){
$.get('http://localhost:8080/messages',(data) => {
    data.forEach(addMessages); })  } 

function postMessage(message){
$.post('http://localhost:8080/messages', message)
}
```

Comment: Is only the name undefined? What is undefined? How did you test it to find out it was undefined?

Comment: @kevin both the message and name was undefined. Its was a mistake of my own i haven't  added any ID names .

Answer (score -1):

In your html, you misspelled your textarea's id. It is `id="mesage"` instead of `id="message"` with two 's'. And you never set the id of #name. Fix these.

```
<input class="form-control" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Name">

<textarea placeholder="Message" class="form-control" id="message" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Makes sure that your variable, which u will send is valid. I recommend you to use the chrome debugger in these situations.

Comment: you are a star mate. I was really careless thanks for your time . can help with any suggest any sites or references which could be a base to become expert in nodejs as i cannot find anything yet..?